# Tagging systems

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Can someone tell me more about tagging systems like facebook, youtube, instagram and similar sites have. On posts and photos...
If you have some examples it would be great and don't ask me for code because I didn't done any of coding... In my mind it is something mixed with live search that starts after some symbol like $ or # or something else and on click on some value it shows that value inside text where you typed it.... 
I know it is mostly ajax but if you have some examples it would be great. Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Tagging is like Comments. You have to make sql table, put a reference to the item that it's tagging, to the tagger, tag contents like the person that we tagged, and some additional datas of tag (like the position of the tag in a photo).
So we will got a table like this:

```
ID ID_IMAGE ID_TAGGER ID_TARGET tag_position_x tag_position_y
```

Now that you have made you table you need to build a php page where you will retrieve the tags. Then you need to make the front end code, which will need some js code so that the tag will be placed in position(tag_position_x,tag_position_y) in a photo. This can be done like this:

```
//some css code 
container_img{
  position : relative;
  background : rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
}
.tag{
  position : absolute;
}
```

and the js will be like (in jquery):

```
$(".tag").each(function() {
   $( this ).css("top",$(this).data("position-x"));
   $( this ).css("top",$(this).data("position-y"));
});
```

Now what I gave you is hints so you know what you have to do.

Comment: I didn't downvoted, but I don't think you should waste your time on answering question of lazy users such as this OP, when there are so many other good questions worth answering instead (I'll upvote for sympathy)

Comment: Oh i use that already for moving divs over page and didnt tought about that... Thanks mate Do you know about tagging in textbox how should click from one field from list input that person in that text box?

Comment: @Knowless You're wrong, and reported

Comment: Thank you @Alon for your sympathy :D

Comment: @Knowless are you serious?

Comment: yea why not? @rsabir

Comment: OK, this can be a little tricky. I have never done it but here's my point of view: Like tags of images, you have also to build a new table where you would have:
`ID ID_COMMENT ID_TARGET ORDER_IN_COMMENT`

 Now the thing is you have to check in backend if there's a special character or combination of characters chosen by you and revealing that there's a comment. 

Let's say that `$^TAGS$$` is the combination chosen. Then you have to replace each combination with the corresponding `<a href="Person_Page">$Person</a>` (use the `ORDER_IN_COMMENT`).

Comment: For the process of tagging, you need some listener that will fire an autocomplete when it recongnise some special character (like #). I suggest you to use an api like [Taggle.js](http://sean.is/poppin/tags)